# Mask-javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть поле тип документа,и поле номер документа при выборе определенного вида документа из поле тип документа на поле номер документа должен отображать символ N автоматом с маской.А у меня наоборот N отображается только,после ввода.Проблема в чем?Поделитесь мыслями.Заранее спасибо!

```
$("#<%=PC%>_DocType").live('change', function () {           
    $('#<%=PC%>_PassNumber').val('');            
    var docType = this.value;
    if (docType == 1) {
        $("#<%=PC%>_PassNumber").unmask();
        $("#<%=PC%>_PassNumber").mask("N?9999?9999");
    }            
    else if (docType == 49) {
        $("#<%=PC%>_PassNumber").unmask();
        $("#<%=PC%>_PassNumber").mask("A?9999?9999");
    }
    else if (docType == 2) {
        $("#<%=PC%>_PassNumber").unmask();
        $("#<%=PC%>_PassNumber").mask("99999?9999");
    }
    else  (docType == 4) {
        $("#<%=PC%>_PassNumber").unmask();
        $("#<%=PC%>_PassNumber").mask("99999?9999");
    } 
}
```

Comment: без кода не поможем

Answer (score 2):

Замените `change` на универсальное событие `input`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput

Событие срабатывает каждый раз, когда содержимое поля меняется, а не только тогда, когда вы переключите фокус (как делает change).